# string being treated as a number when using if statement

Tags: php

i am using an if statement to compare 2 variables against each other, mainly in this case barcodes. i have noticed if they are leading with zeros and the only difference is one variable as more zeros at the beginning and the rest is the same its giving a true result as if they are the same, which in INT/NUMBER format that would be true, however i have checked and both are strings, so cant get my head around why it thinks "000005" and "0000005" are the same when they are not.

```
    echo "<pre>";
    $params['barcode_new'] = "0000005";
    $params['barcode_old'] = "000005";
    echo "var type : " .gettype($params['barcode_new']) ."<br>";

    if ($params['barcode_old'] == $params['barcode_new']) {
      echo "Master barcode already set to {$params['barcode_new']} <br>";
      print_r($params);
    }
```

Comment: use bitoperator **===** instead of *==*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Identical` `===` operator instead. With `===` it will not convert the values and will match for the exact. Try with -

```
 if ($params['barcode_old'] === $params['barcode_new']) {
```

> If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the comparison performed numerically. These rules also apply to the switch statement. The type conversion does not take place when the comparison is === or !== as this involves comparing the type as well as the value.

Answer (score 6):

Strings will be compared per character. Numbers by their value. So the strings differ and numbers will be equal. For type correctness use `===` to check if the values are identical and == if they are equal (e.g. numbers)

```
<?php
  var_dump("0000005" == "000005");
  var_dump("0000005" === "000005");
?>
```

> bool(true)
>   bool(false)